# run func() based on what time it is

Tags: c, timer

i wrote some code that monitors a directory DIR with **inotify()** and when a file gets moved in DIR i get a .txt output of that file(its an nfcapd file with flows of my network interface). This happens every 5 minutes.

After that, i used Snort's DPX starter kit, with which you can extend Snort by writing your own preprocessor. This preprocessor,like all the others, is just a function that's executed every time a new packet is available. My problem is that i want, when a new file gets exported from my previous code(so every 5 minutes), to read that file inside the preprocessor's function.

So, is there any way of getting the time and executing only if it's the desired time?

```
if (time is 15:36){
    func(output.txt);}
```

i'm writing in c.

Thanks

Comment: You can do this but it smells like bad design. Can you give more details on what you're doing ?

Comment: Why can't you run the code based on the `inotify`?

Comment: they are separate source files. The "monitor_nfcapd" (the first-one) is outside Snort and has to remain like this. Also, i can't use
    inotify 
for this,since the preprocessor function executes something like 1000times/s(for every packet). So, i can only just check the time or a flag or something like this,every time the preprocessor function executes

Comment: @cnicutar i'm new to programming, so yes, it certainly is bad design!! :p

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```
#include <time.h>
...

time_t t = time(NULL); //obtain current time in seconds
struct tm broken_time;
localtime_r(&t, &broken_time); // split time into fields

if(broken_time.tm_hour == 15 && broken_time.tm_min == 36) { //perform the check
    func(output.txt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `inotify`, I'm assuming your environment supports POSIX signals.

You can use [`alarm()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/alarm.html) to raise a signal after a predetermined amount of time has passed and have the [appropriate signal handler](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigaction.html) do whatever work you need to do. It would avoid what I think is going to end up being a very ugly infinite loop in your code.

So, in your case, the function handling `SIGALRM` would not need to worry what time it was, it would know that a predetermined amount of time has passed by the fact that it was entered. However, you'll need to provide some context that function can access to know *what* to do, kind of hard to suggest how without seeing your code.

I'm not entirely sure you're going down the right path with this, but using `alarm()` would probably be the sanest approach given what you described.

Comment: i think i just needed something like gettimeofday(), but thanks, i'll try both!

Comment: No worries, sounds like an interesting project :) If you end up doing something completely different, don't hesitate to provide your own answer as well.